# Quickly create List out of part of another IList

Tags: c#, list

I would love to know if there is a standard way to create a list out of elements of another list up to specified index like in python, for example:

```
List1(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
List2 = new List(List1, upToIndex = 4)
List2(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I need a really fast way of doing it and want to avoid a simple "for" loop if there is a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `list.GetRange(startIndex, count)`

```
List<int> inputList = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9};
List<int> newList = inputList.GetRange(0, 4); //Output: 1,2,3,4
```

If you want to get sub list from given list using `startingIndex` and `endingIndex`, then you can do some basic math

something like

```
List<int> newList = inputList.GetRange(startIndex, (endIndex - startIndex));  //(endIndex - startIndex) this will return count of sub list
```

Or you can try Linq operation, suggested by [@Crowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276469/crowcoder),

```
List<int> newList = inputList.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex).ToList();
```

If you are using C# 8, then you can use range instead of `Skip` and `Take`,

```
var newList = inputList.Range[startIndex..count]; //where count will be (endIndex - startIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, also for future is there a way to get range between specific indexes?

Comment: Note that in C# 8.0 ranges the endpoint is exclusive, i.e. element `endIndex` is not included. See: [Take C# 8.0 for a spin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/). So if we want `upToIndex = 4` then we have to write `var newList = inputList.Range[0..5];`, where 5 is the length when starting at index 0.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, thanks for your input, I updated my answer

Comment: endpoint - start point is the length, i.e., `[start..end].Count == end - start`. If we have two consecutive ranges starting at index 0 having a length of 5, we have `Range [0..5]` and ` Range[5..10]` with the indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I.e., the exclusive endpoint of the first range is equal to the inclusive start point of the following range. This is comparable to `s.Substring(0, 5)` and `s.Substring(5, 5)` for strings with `public string Substring (int startIndex, int length);`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can take with `System.Linq`.

```
var subset = yourList.Take(4).ToList();
```